# In awk, how can I increase an array index when it encounters a new string?

Tags: arrays, loops, awk

I'm trying to parse ls output (I know it's frowned upon, but I need to for an assignment.) I need to count up the number of directories for each user and print that out underneath their username.

I have a for loop to print out user names/number of directories:

```
for (users in uid){ 
       x++
       totalUsers++;
       printf("User: %s\n", users);


       if(dirs[x]>0)
        printf("   dirs: %s\n", dirs[x]);

    }
```

And I've tried this:

```
if(dirs[x] < $2) {
    dirs[x]=$2  
    x++
}
```

but that won't link the directory count to the user field.

Basically, I'm trying to get this output:

```
user: mce237

   files:

   all/hidden: ( 52 / 12 )

   dirs: 4

   file storage: 2729344 B
```

from this:

```
-rw-------  1 mce237 students     199 2020-03-01 18:41:59 .build1276786824731864129.log

-rw-------  1 mce237 students     199 2020-03-01 20:18:42 .build291177188595028335.log

-rw-------  1 mce237 students     199 2020-03-01 20:10:44 .build4195866878600813549.log

-rw-------  1 mce237 students     199 2020-03-01 20:08:55 .build4503681510908034369.log

-rw-------  1 mce237 students     199 2020-03-01 18:18:44 .build4964061885086964943.log

-rw-------  1 mce237 students     199 2020-03-01 20:17:13 .build5474334865226720725.log

-rw-------  1 mce237 students     199 2020-03-01 19:08:39 .build6322670020019345604.log

-rw-------  1 mce237 students     420 2020-03-01 20:08:08 .build8057453026527719771.log
```

Comment: Why not `users[$3]++`? and `if ($8 ~ /^[.]/) {hidden[$3]++` and so on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can index everything on the `user` (`$3`) and then keep separate arrays for each of the quantities you need to track. You can check if the first character in the first field is `'d'` to determine if the file is a directory and you can check whether the first character in the filename is `'.'` to determine if the file is hidden (it's up to you if you want to count each directory in the total for the user -- if not, add and `else`)

To track each of the quantities and then output in the `END` rule, you could do something similar to:

```
ls -youroptions | awk '{
    user[$3]++
    storage[$3]+=$5
    if ($1 ~ /^d/)
        dir[$3]++
    if ($8 ~ /^[.]/)
        hidden[$3]++
}
END {
    for (i in user) 
        printf "user: %s\nfiles:\n(all/hidden): (%d/%d)\ndirs: %d\nstorage: %ld\n",
        i,user[i],hidden[i],dirs[i],storage[i]
}'
```

(**note:** when parsing `ls` you will probably want to add `NR > 1 {...}` to avoid the `"total"` line printed as the 1st line -- and different options and LOCALE settings may produce different field orderings than you show)

**Example Output**

Using the listing your provided as input (assuming you don't really have blank lines between each line of `ls` output), the following output would be produced:

```
user: mce237
files:
(all/hidden): (8/8)
dirs: 0
storage: 1813
```

This should show you one approach to handling the different counts in separate arrays all synced by using a common field as the index.

Comment: thank you so much! this is just the breakthrough I needed to get this done. :)

Comment: Glad it helped. `awk` is the Swiss-Army-Knife for all things text, and once you make friends with the fact that it process one record (line) at a time and you can write as many rules as  you need to process each line - it's really just normal programming in each rule `:)` Good luck with your scripting!